# How to declare play json dependency?

Tags: scala, sbt, play-json

My `build.sbt` file (sbt version is `0.13.8`):

```
lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  version := "1.0.0",
  scalaVersion := "2.11.6"
)

resolvers += "Typesafe Repo" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(commonSettings: _*).
  settings(
    name := "myapp",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "com.typesafe.play" % "play-json" % "2.3.4",
      "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.11" % "2.2.4" % "test",
      "junit" % "junit" % "4.12" % "test"
    )
  )

scalacOptions ++= Seq("-unchecked", "-feature", "-deprecation")
```

I get this error when trying to compile my project:

```
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:update for the full output.
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play-json_2.11;2.3.4: not found
[error] Total time: 0 s, completed Apr 17, 2015 5:59:28 PM
```

How can I get this play-json library for my `scala 2.11.6`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to tell sbt which scala version should use.

You can either be explicit:

```
"com.typesafe.play" % "play-json_2.11" % "2.3.4",
```

Or use `%%` ([sbt doc](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Library-Dependencies.html#Getting+the+right+Scala+version+with)) as follows to tell sbt to use `scalaVersion` :

```
"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.3.4",
```

Answer (score 4):

You can see all of `com.typesafe.play`'s `play-json` versions [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.play/play-json_2.11). They don't have a `2.3.4` version; try using `2.4.0-M3` instead.

```
"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.4.0-M3"
```

Mind the double `%%` so `scalaVersion` is used properly to resolve the dependency.

Comment: Except typesafe's repo is added for resolving which has lots of other versions: http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/play/play-json_2.11/

Comment: I tried the 2.4.0-M3 version but it needs Java 8 and for this app I'm limited to Java 7.

Comment: Typesafe's repo does have older versions that should work with Java 7. See @dalewijnand's comment on my answer.